# How to return a value from ForEach method of Java 8

Tags: foreach, return

I've the below method where I pass a varargs as input. I'm trying to avoid HeapPollution so besides annotating with Suppresswarnings I also wanted to make sure I validate that the class of every arg in my varargs are of the same or descendants of the class. My problem though is, if I find that the classes don't match I want to return false; With ForEach method (which returns only void I can just do a return. Is there a way to directly exit from my ForEach loop by returning false. I don't want to use the enhanced For Loop [just because I'm learning forEach :-)] but achieve what I want with the ForEach method and lambda expression. Is there a way at all?

Thanks for any help you may offer!

```
public final <T> boolean exists(T valueToCheck, @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T... listOfPossibleValues) {
    if (valueToCheck == null) return false;
    Arrays.asList(listOfPossibleValues).forEach((T value) -> 
{ if (!(valueToCheck.getClass().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass()))) return;          else System.out.println(value.getClass()); });
    for (T value : listOfPossibleValues){
        if (value != null ) {
            if (value.equals(valueToCheck)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the below and I think this solves my purpose. Ofcourse not using ForEach but using streams and a lambda expression.

```
     return Arrays.asList(listOfPossibleValues).stream().filter(value -> !(valueToCheck.getClass().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass()))).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 0;
```